# What to do with answer containing images coming from a commercial site?

Tags: discussion

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425486/3102264) give a possible solution to the question [Is it possible to use WebRTC to streaming video from Server to Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17552333/3102264)

However this answer :

- suggest a commercial solution without indicate it is
- contains images that are copy from [WebRTC Media & Broadcasting Server](http://flashphoner.com/webrtc-streaming-server-for-live-broadcasting-and-webinars/)

Is this acceptable on stack overflow ? Should I flag it to close it ?

UPDATE:
Others answers from same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2819075/nick) link also same commercial site :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635009/3102264
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24544142/3102264
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24426340/3102264

Comment: That pretty much looks like spam to me.

Comment: Perhaps I understand wrongly spam, the answer is correctly related to the question, and could be considered. But it is perhaps commercial actions ?

Comment: This user has posted 66 answers. Almost all of them link to the same site, with no disclosure. If that's not spam, I don't know what is.

Comment: There's a certain Lizard working on this particular case, now...

Comment: *This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.* I guess your confusion is regarding the second portion? It qualifies for the first, but could technically be considered relevant for that technology. It is definitely promotional, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I deleted some of the more dodgy looking posts and sent the user a warning. If they're affiliated with the company that makes WebRTC Media & Broadcasting Server, they need to disclose that affiliation. It's fine if they're just supporting the product on questions that specifically ask about it, but promoting the product on other questions is not cool.